# How can I automatically generate good accessors for Javascript?

Tags: javascript

At the moment I'm implement some Javascript object in the following manner:

```
var graph = (function(){
    var width = 200;
    var height = 300;
    [...]

    var obj={
    width: function(value){
        if(value===undefined) return width;
        width=value;
        return obj;
    },
    height: function(value){
        if(value===undefined) return height;
        height=value;
        return obj;
    },[...]
    };
    return obj;
})();


graph.width(200)
    .height(graph.width()*2);
```

My accessors are all defined in an extremely similar manner, mainly to allow for a sort of chaining API.

Defining the width and the height like this is really annoying, is there some sort of pattern I can use to still be able to take advantage of the closure-y stuff, without having to copy-paste the same function n times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a private object, too — not the most horrible thing in the world:

```
function generate(me, prop) {
    return function(value) {
        if(arguments.length === 0) return me[prop];
        me[prop] = value;
        return this;
    };
}

var graph = (function() {
    var me = {
        width:  200,
        height: 300
    };

    var obj = {
        width:  generate(me, 'width'),
        height: generate(me, 'height')
    };

    return obj;
})();
```

Comment: That doesn't work because he wants to allow method chaining. Your anonymous function doesn't return anything when a value is set.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that generates those functions and then call it, but I can't say it's pretty since you don't have neat access to closure variables.

Please please please *don't* use this in production, this is just a proof of concept.

What we'll be doing here is introduce a **macro** into the language, that macro will be called `generate` . Calling `generate(propName)` will generate a getter in the style you want for your property. We'll wrap the code in a function, and then process the macro ourselves. **This is just to prove the concept.**

The syntax is something like:

```
var graph = Capture(function () {
    var width = 200;
    var height = 300;

    var obj = {
        width: generate(width),
        height:generate(height)
    };
    return obj;
});
```

First of all:

#### [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RYW7V/)

What we do is the following:

#### 1) We wrap your IIFE in a Capture function, this will process the content

```
var graph = Capture(function () {
    [..]
});
```

#### We use string processing to peplace the `generate` keyword with the appropriate content

```
function Capture(src) {
    src = src.toString()
    src = src.replace(/generate\((.*?)\)/g, function (a, b) {
        return "function(value){"+
            "if(value===undefined){ return "+b+"; } "+b+" = value; return obj;}";
    });
    console.log(src)
    return eval("("+src+")")();
}
```

We match `generate(SOMETHING)` and replace it with the function you want with that property. This is what the replace does.

#### 3) We evaluate that function, and then call it

Since we evaluated it all at once, it'll have access to the closure. This gives us what we wanted and the shorter syntax.

### What *should* we do instead?

The better alternative is to use privates with the `_varName` notation and avoid closure variables altogether for these purposes. This is what most libraries do, it's very clear, and you don't have these sort of problems, you can simply use bracket notation and `bind` for the syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, could you explain point to where I can figure out how to use `bind` for this problem?